# RSpec "undefined local variable or method `user'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have the following test written in RSpec:

```
describe '#create' do
  ...
  it 'redirects users to profile page' do
    response.should redirect_to user_path(user)
  end
  ...
...
```

And the following in my `UsersController`:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end
end
```

Does anyone know why this is returning the following error:

`NameError: undefined local variable or method 'user'`

I also tried changing this to be `root_url` in both cases instead of `user_path(user)` and it gave a different error saying:

`Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>`

Does anyone know what the issue might be? I have double-checked my code and have seen similar questions posted online, but haven't been able to find a solution. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `assigns` just creates an instance variable and doesn't populate it without having another `post :create` above it.

So, for future reference, here's the correct code:

```
it 'redirects to the users profile page' do
  post :create, user: attributes_for(:user)
  response.should redirect_to user_path(assigns :user)
end
```

However, you must use the `assigns :user` as Mori suggested in order to create the instance variable in the second part. E.G. You can't simple do `user_path(:user)` or `user_path(@user)`.

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rspec Rail's `assigns` method to access controller instance variables:

```
it 'redirects users to profile page' do
  response.should redirect_to user_path(assigns :user)
end
```

Here `assigns :user` is equivalent to`controller.instance_variable_get :@user`.

As per @Justin's comment below, he was also missing the line to call the controller action:

```
post :create, user: attributes_for(:user)
```

Comment: I tried inputting that and it throws this error now: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}`. However, I do have `resources :users` in my routes.rb file, a show action in the controller, and a show view. Any ideas why that's happening?

Comment: Well, in the controller it should pass the `id` with @user, do you mean in the spec? I checked the `test.log` file and it seems that users are being input correctly into the database, but is there another way to test that?

Comment: Try testing `user_path` in the console with something like `app.user_path(User.first)` to see if the route works as expected.

Comment: Hmm, it shows a routing error saying that no routes match. But I have `resources :users` in the routes.rb file. And I also tried doing `resources :users, :only => [:new, :show]`

Comment: Ah, I found the problem! It turns out that assigns doesn't actually create the object, you need to add another `post :create, user: attributes_for(:user)` within that `it` above the original line and then use the assigns that you suggested!